# Как сделать так, чтобы эта функция была анимирована?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы эта функция была анимирована?

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".header").css({
                width: "100%",
                position: "fixed"
            })
        } else {
            $(".header").css({
                width: "auto",
                position: "relative"
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Держите: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1aDsL.gif

Comment: @VladD порвал! Лучший ответ ))

Comment: Что вы хотите анимировать?

Comment: Вот если б тема была "как занимировать функцию", то замечательно бы подходило отвечающему - прям третья часть и от другого автора :D

Comment: @VladD, классно!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".header").animate({
                width: "100%",
                position: "fixed"
            },5000);
        } else {
            $(".header").animate({
                width: "auto",
                position: "relative"
            },5000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ваш код не валиден.

Comment: Почему не валиден?

Comment: А вы точно поставили `,5000` туда куда нужно? ;)