# scroll js jquery

Tags: jquery

Имеется код который в зависимости от скролла выдает разные стили

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
            $(".header").css({
                width: "100%",
                position: "fixed"
            })
        } else {
            $(".header").css({
                width: "auto",
                position: "relative"
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Как сделать что бы он плавно появлялся стилизовался во время скролла?

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы задавать новый вопрос, лучше бы отредактировали предыдущий

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473711/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0